# php HTTP_REFERER header, how to turn off or leave blank

Tags: php, http, http-headers, php4

I'm using the following simple PHP proxy script but am getting a sporadic message at the destination site.

I'm thinking that perhaps it may have something to do with the HTTP_REFERER header, although I'm not explicitly defining it.

Can anyone tell me how to explicitly turn off or leave the HTTP_REFERER header blank?

Thanks in advance!

```
$url = $_GET['path'];
readfile($path);
```

Comment: What message do you get?

Comment: 403 Forbidden: The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.

In  googling for the same error, I recall seeing an addition to this error, saying in effect to ensure the the HTTP_REFERER was blank. Anyways, am troubleshooting a variety of possibilities right now since it is a sporadic issue.

Comment: All right, so your *real* question is probably the exact opposite of your *actual* question: How do I send REFERER headers along with my request? :)

Comment: ok ... How do I send REFERER headers along with my request?;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the HTTP wrapper to `readfile()` sends any special headers, let alone REFERER.

What leads you to the conclusion that it does?

Comment: Agreed - I'm rather confused by the OP's question .

Comment: Sidenote: 
That snippet is a security concern:
ie: host.com?path=../../etc/passwd

$url = $_GET['path'];
readfile($path);

You get the idea?

Comment: @Mr-sk.... Better yet... `?path=../../../../../../../etc/passwd` to ensure you **get to the root of the problem** if you *know what I'm sayinnnn* (lol)